# Reading from arbitrary sd card folder

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card, android-permissions

I am trying to read a dictionary on sd card (content of the folder is managed by third party app - ex. dropbox).

Although i granted my app permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The app will be used only on one type of device Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 5.0.2) so I know the exact path to sdCard and the file I am trying to read: /storage/extSdCard/sip.png

When I call:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/storage/extSdCard/sip.png");
```

It throws:

> exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/extSdCard/sip.png:
>   open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I also tried:

```
grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), new Uri.parse("/storage/extSdCard"),
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

What do I need to do to get access to the file?

Answer (score 2):

> What do I need to do to get access to the file?

You have no direct filesystem access to arbitrary locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+.

If possible, move the file elsewhere (e.g., [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html)).

Or, [use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html) and have the user choose the file, then use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to work on the content identified by the `Uri` that you get in `onActivityResult()` from your `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` request.

Comment: That app uses dynamic reading files that are on removable storage and synced by another app. Is there another way to read bigger amount of files?

Comment: @M.Sestak: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the link. This will help a lot while explaining it to the customers